# Ruby Quick Class Instance Scope

Tags: ruby, scope

I have a quick problem that probably comes down to something stupid. I have a class that extends `OAuth::AccessToken` and uses instance variables (`@`) so that each time it constructs an object, those variables will be unique that instance. However, when I try to return the final object from this class, I get an error. A quick example:

```
require 'oauth'

class OauthFigshare < OAuth::AccessToken
    def initialize (consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken, accesstokensecret)
    @consumerkey = consumerkey
    @consumersecret = consumersecret
    @accesstoken = accesstoken
    @accesstokensecret = accesstokensecret
    @apiurl = "http://api.figshare.com"

    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@consumerkey,@consumersecret,{:site=> @apiurl})
    @token = { :oauth_token => @accesstoken, :oauth_token_secret => @accesstokensecret}

    puts @consumer.class
    puts @token


    @client = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(@consumer, @token)
    puts @client
    puts @client.get('/v1/my_data/articles')
    return @client
   end
end
```

The problem is that when I check inside the class to see if the token is working, it does. However, when I check against the constructed object outside the class, it doesn't work.

`@client.get(url) returns Net::HTTPOk` calling from in the class

```
auth = OauthFigshare.new(inputs)
auth.get(url)
```

This returns `Net::HTTPUnauthorized`

What am I not getting about scope here?

**Edit to include actual class**

Comment: Please fill in more of the code in the _Here I do xyz..._ sections.

Comment: I've included the actual class in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the initialize method is not used.  It seems like you actually want to override self.new instead.

Comment: I was under the impression that all ruby blocks were expressions that returned some value. So thats not true for the initialize method? I originally just had the last line constructing the client, assuming it would return that object, but when I hit the issue, I wanted to check explicitly.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the `initialize` method to `self.new` works, if I try to separate the two (so that only if `new` is called with variables will it call `initialize`) it seems to break that functionality of the original `new` method.

Comment: Every method has a return value, and new is a different method than initialize.  New calls initialize but ignores the return value.